# My vote count in my profile is incorrect

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, voting

My "Impact" box lists my vote count as follows:

[image]

However, when I look at the breakdown, it's below:

[image]

I initially assumed that the "Impact" box was just being cached (because it seems to be slow to update), but then I noticed that the number in the "Impact" box is actually considerably *higher* than the number I see in the votes history breakdown; if it were simply a matter of slow-to-update cached statistics, I'd expect to see the opposite pattern.

Does the second number exclude votes on posts that have been deleted or something like that, or is this a genuine bug? (The fact that my Meta profile, where I hardly ever vote to close, shows the exact opposite pattern - 312 votes cast in the Impact box vs. 320 in the breakdown - would seem to suggest that the former is the case).

Comment: I wonder if the impact box includes votes on deleted posts where the all tab does not since you can't see deleted posts yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Exactly as you describe. The number in the grey box is the total number of all votes you've ever cast. The number in your votes tab is just a count of how many are being displayed back to you. We don't display votes on deleted posts to users in that list, so they're not included in that count.

Keep in mind that the grey box is only counting upvotes and downvotes. That count in your votes tab is for *all* votes you are allowed to see, including other votes that aren't counted in the grey box. The count is actually much further off than you might be expecting.

When *I* view your votes tab with my staff privileges, the actual count is 10,219.

Comment: When you have 10K do you see the "right" number?  For instance I see 19,231 on my all tab

Comment: @NathanOliver Apparently not, it shows 23,369 for you. Though I couldn't tell you exactly which ones were being hidden from 10k users (I don't know).

Comment: OK.  Interesting.  I wonder what it is I can't see.  A cursory glance looks like it is deleted posts which have been down voted.  I say this because I know I have but I don't see any.

Comment: @NathanOliver up- and downvotes on deleted posts aren't listed even if you have 10k rep. My 'all' tab shows ~5000 votes (including close & del votes on deleted posts) vs the ~10000 in the impact box.

Comment: 10,219? Wow, that's a *lot* higher than I see. A lot higher than I expected, too. Well, I guess I *have* been using up a lot of downvotes and close votes on tag cleanup lately... :)

Comment: Yeah, I was guessing that the discrepancy between the pattern of my Meta votes and the pattern of my SO votes was the fact that things I vote on in SO are a lot more likely to be deleted eventually (since a lot of my SO votes are close votes and I tend to participate in tag cleanups and burniation, a lot of which either Roomba or get deleted for one reason or another).